# Is the number of degrees of freedom always equals one?

Tags: degrees-of-freedom

If the number of degrees of freedom is the minimum number of independent variables necessary to describe the system, does this mean that this number is always equal to one? For example, if, as it seems to us, we need $\mathbf n$ variables to describe the system, then we can always put 1 variable in accordance with these $\mathbf n$ variables, because the sets $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^n$ has the same cardinality, and then the degree of freedom of the system will be equal to one.

Comment: What does the cardinality have to do with anything? They are not isomorphic as vector spaces. The point is that one variable can vary independently of the other variables.

Comment: You can think of DoF as similar to dimensions in a vector space. Every element in a vector space is a single vector, but the vector space still has $n$ dimensions.

Comment: But based on the same cardinality, we can also consider a one-dimensional space describing the system, right?

Comment: @Mikhail no. Having the same cardinality means that there exists a map from one to the other (with subjectivity etc). But if you change one of the $n$ independent variables in the $n$-dimensional description then you change the *whole* value in the 1-dimensional "corresponding" value. That means that the independence between variation of the different DOFs is lost under this map. There is no way to "change a part of the number without affecting the other parts of the same number" in the 1D case.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce degrees of freedom you need symmetries. You cannot have it exactly without symmetries.

Typically you have to consider the manifold that is described by some holonomic constraints. This can reduce the number of freedoms by providing a way to express a subset of coordinates by the remaining ones not in this subset. But it is not in general admissible just from the structure of the vector spaces to infer a reduction of degrees of freedom. Say you have n particles in a box and they only interact when hitting each other, i.e.  the ideal gas. Of course you can say that each particle only moves along a line until it hits a wall or another particle, but this does not necessary reduce the degrees of freedom to one, because a line would be one dimensional. As the particles don't interact you have a few subtle symmetries like homogeneity  - which leads to constance of certain fractions of extensive quantities - and indistinguishability of the particles. Those symmetries in turn reduce your degrees of freedom but the point is that the symmetries are key here. With those symmetries you end up at equipartition. Without you would not necessarily.

Consider you had a system of n completely different particles, you would not necessarily end up with eqipartition as the most massive particle could always transfer a considerable amount of energy to the least massive one upon scattering. So you could not reduce your degrees of freedom in this case as the system lacks symmetry.

So as I understand it, you cannot just by the appearance of the cardinality draw a conclusion about reduction of degrees of freedom.